# What is wrong with this Blender node setup?

Tags: blender

When I attach the normal map texture node to the Principled BSDF node for my plane I get a distorted reflection from the single light source (a point light). What am I doing wrong here? I've attached an image of my node setup.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I learned from an online tutorial that I need a Normal Map node between the normal.jpg texture node and the BSDF.normal socket. Once I put that in, everything worked as expected.